# Different JSON Pattern in Data Factory

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a data source with this structure.

```
{
  "records": [
    { 
      "dateRep": "02/04/2020",
      "day": "2",
      "month": "4",
      "year": "2020",
      "cases": "26",
      "deaths": "0",
      "countriesAndTerritories": "Afghanistan",
      "geoId": "AF",
      "countryterritoryCode": "AFG",
      "popData2018": "37172386"
    }
}
```

In the azure data factory, I need to create a row for every entry in the record array. Does anybody know, how to realize this?

Comment: This is kind of a Transform and ADF doesn’t inherently have much T ability, unless you’re thinking of using Mapping Data Flows.  I need to know more about the source and target really.

Comment: Also, what does your desired output look like?  "one row for every entry in the record array" isn't quite enough information.

Comment: The source ist this here. https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/json/

The target is a simple table in an azure sql database. There is a column for every attribute of the object in the records array. 

The source shouldn’t have the leading brackets and the records attribute. It should be just an array with simple objects.

Comment: Hi @KrisKul If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please reference my steps:

This is the demo json,  I copied from the link to my Blob Storage as **A.json**:

```
{   
  "records": 
    [
    { 
      "dateRep": "05/04/2020",
      "day": "5",
      "month": "4",
      "year": "2020",
      "cases": "35",
      "deaths": "1",
      "countriesAndTerritories": "Afghanistan",
      "geoId": "AF",
      "countryterritoryCode": "AFG",
      "popData2018": "37172386"
    }, 
    { 
      "dateRep": "04/04/2020",
      "day": "4",
      "month": "4",
      "year": "2020",
      "cases": "0",
      "deaths": "0",
      "countriesAndTerritories": "Afghanistan",
      "geoId": "AF",
      "countryterritoryCode": "AFG",
      "popData2018": "37172386"
    }, 
    { 
      "dateRep": "03/04/2020",
      "day": "3",
      "month": "4",
      "year": "2020",
      "cases": "43",
      "deaths": "0",
      "countriesAndTerritories": "Afghanistan",
      "geoId": "AF",
      "countryterritoryCode": "AFG",
      "popData2018": "37172386"
    }
    ]
}
```

Copy active choose the **A.json** as **Source dataset**:
[image]

**Sink dataset**:

I create this dep table as sink table in my Azure SQL database:

```
create table dep (
    dateRep date,
       day int,
      month int,
      year int,
      cases int,
      deaths int,
      countriesAndTerritories varchar(100),
      geoId varchar(50),
      countryterritoryCode varchar(50),
      popData2018  int  
    )
```

[image]

**Mappings**:

[image]

**Run the pipeline:**

[image]

**Check the data in Azure SQL database:**

[image]

This will help you create a row for every entry in the record array.

Hope this helps.